# When to use app/code vs app/design

Tags: magento2, module, frontend, design, code

I saw two topics about that but I'm still not sure.

I'm discovering Magento 2, I'm a frontend developer and right now, I just want to make my company website's header and footer (html, css) (so a theme)

Which folder should I use ? `app/code` or `app/design`.

If I'm creating a new module, I have to create all phtml files, layout, etc... in `app/code/../view/frontend/templates/xx.phtml` but if I'm overriding an existing module, eg : module-theme or module-catalog, I'm doing it in `app/design/frontend/../../templates/xx.phtml`?

Comment: For creating a new module you would place all you code inside app/code/vendorname/modulename/ For editing a theme you can either create a child theme of your current theme and do any changes to that. If you just want to do a few simple amends you can edit your theme which is situated in app/design, just remember that version control is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the approach you want to have.

You need to understand few things.

In the app/design, you only can edit files: phtml, html, less, css, xml
The design is last in the chain than anything that happens in the app/code.
So if something happens in luma design, you can have troubles changing things in the app/code.

In the app/code this is a place for new modules.
You can't access the mage lib here.
Your can't change the templates that exist in the current design or any of its parent.